# Benchmark switch, binary search and if-else

Tags: performance, comparative-review, go, binary-search, benchmarking

Just for curiosity I have done some benchmark  for testing the best performance between switch, binary-search, and if-else statement.
here is the code :

```
package switchStatement

type Badge struct {
    score int
    badge string
}

func initiateBadges() []Badge {
    badge := []Badge{
        {score: 4501, badge: "gold-1.gif"},
        {score: 10001, badge: "gold-2.gif"},
        {score: 15001, badge: "gold-3.gif"},
        {score: 30001, badge: "gold-4.gif"},
        {score: 45001, badge: "gold-5.gif"},
        {score: 50001, badge: "diamond-1.gif"},
        {score: 100001, badge: "diamond-2.gif"},
        {score: 150001, badge: "diamond-3.gif"},
        {score: 200001, badge: "diamond-4.gif"},
        {score: 500001, badge: "diamond-5.gif"},
    }

    return badge
}

func GetReputationBadgeImprove(score int) string {

    badges := initiateBadges()

    //search score using binary search
    index := BinarySearchBadge(badges, score)
    if index == -1 {
        return "badges-off.jpg"
    }
    return badges[index].badge
}

func BinarySearchBadge(badges []Badge, score int) int {
    low := 0
    high := len(badges) - 1
    middle := (high + low) / 2

    for low <= high {
        //checking to avoid index out of range
        if middle == len(badges)-1 {
            return middle
        }

        if badges[middle].score <= score && badges[middle+1].score > score {
            return middle
        } else if badges[middle].score >= score {
            high = middle - 1

        } else {
            low = middle + 1
        }

        middle = (high + low) / 2
    }

    return -1
}

func GetReputationBadgeImproveSwitchCase(score int) string {
    switch {
    case score >= 500001:
        return "diamond-5.gif"
    case score >= 200001:
        return "diamond-4.gif"
    case score >= 150001:
        return "diamond-3.gif"
    case score >= 100001:
        return "diamond-2.gif"
    case score >= 50001:
        return "diamond-1.gif"
    case score >= 45001:
        return "gold-5.gif"
    case score >= 30001:
        return "gold-4.gif"
    case score >= 15001:
        return "gold-3.gif"
    case score >= 10001:
        return "gold-2.gif"
    case score >= 4501:
        return "gold-1.gif"
    default:
        return "badges-off.jpg"
    }
}

func GetReputationBadge(score int) string {

    badge := "badges-off.jpg"
    if score >= 50001 { // Diamond
        badge = "diamond-1.gif"
        if score >= 500001 {
            badge = "diamond-5.gif"
        } else if score >= 200001 {
            badge = "diamond-4.gif"
        } else if score >= 150001 {
            badge = "diamond-3.gif"
        } else if score >= 100001 {
            badge = "diamond-2.gif"
        }
    } else if score >= 4501 { // Gold
        badge = "gold-1.gif"
        if score >= 45001 {
            badge = "gold-5.gif"
        } else if score >= 30001 {
            badge = "gold-4.gif"
        } else if score >= 15001 {
            badge = "gold-3.gif"
        } else if score >= 10001 {
            badge = "gold-4.gif"
        }
    }

    return badge
}
```

And I write some test and benchmark :

```
package switchStatement

import (
    "testing"
)

func TestGetReputationBadge(t *testing.T) {
    result := GetReputationBadgeImproveSwitchCase(10)
    if result != "badges-off.jpg" {
        t.Error("Expected badges-off.jpg got = ", result)
    }
}

func TestGetReputationImprove(testing *testing.T) {

    //using table drive test or tt
    var tt = []struct {
        input    int
        expected string
    }{
        {10, "badges-off.jpg"},
        {100, "badges-off.jpg"},
        {4501, "gold-1.gif"},
        {4561, "gold-1.gif"},
        {13001, "gold-2.gif"},
        {104001, "diamond-2.gif"},
        {594401, "diamond-5.gif"},
    }

    for _, t := range tt {
        actual := GetReputationBadgeImprove(t.input)
        if actual != t.expected {
            testing.Errorf("Test failed expected : %s, actual : %s", t.expected, actual)
        }
    }
}

//binary search
func benchmarkGetReputation(input int, b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        GetReputationBadgeImprove(input)
    }
}

//switch
func benchmarkGetReputationSwitch(input int, b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        GetReputationBadgeImproveSwitchCase(input)
    }
}

//if-else statement
func benchmarkGetReputationIf(input int, b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        GetReputationBadge(input)
    }
}

//benchmark using binary search
func BenchmarkGetReputation1(b *testing.B) { benchmarkGetReputation(10, b) }
func BenchmarkGetReputation2(b *testing.B) { benchmarkGetReputation(4555, b) }
func BenchmarkGetReputation3(b *testing.B) { benchmarkGetReputation(14555, b) }
func BenchmarkGetReputation4(b *testing.B) { benchmarkGetReputation(504001, b) }

//benchmark using switch
func BenchmarkGetReputation1Switch(b *testing.B) { benchmarkGetReputationSwitch(10, b) }
func BenchmarkGetReputation2Switch(b *testing.B) { benchmarkGetReputationSwitch(4555, b) }
func BenchmarkGetReputation3Switch(b *testing.B) { benchmarkGetReputationSwitch(14555, b) }
func BenchmarkGetReputation4Switch(b *testing.B) { benchmarkGetReputationSwitch(504001, b) }

//benchmark if-else statemen
func BenchmarkGetReputation1If(b *testing.B) { benchmarkGetReputation(10, b) }
func BenchmarkGetReputation2If(b *testing.B) { benchmarkGetReputation(4555, b) }
func BenchmarkGetReputation3If(b *testing.B) { benchmarkGetReputation(14555, b) }
func BenchmarkGetReputation4If(b *testing.B) { benchmarkGetReputation(504001, b) }
```

This is the result from my benchmark test :

```
BenchmarkGetReputation1-4           20000000           114 ns/op
BenchmarkGetReputation2-4           10000000           114 ns/op
BenchmarkGetReputation3-4           10000000           113 ns/op
BenchmarkGetReputation4-4           10000000           118 ns/op
BenchmarkGetReputation1Switch-4     2000000000           1.80 ns/op
BenchmarkGetReputation2Switch-4     2000000000           1.80 ns/op
BenchmarkGetReputation3Switch-4     1000000000           2.16 ns/op
BenchmarkGetReputation4Switch-4     2000000000           0.36 ns/op
BenchmarkGetReputation1If-4         10000000           137 ns/op
BenchmarkGetReputation2If-4         10000000           129 ns/op
BenchmarkGetReputation3If-4         10000000           112 ns/op
BenchmarkGetReputation4If-4         10000000           118 ns/op
PASS
ok      github.com/hello/switchStatement    22.554s
```

from there I can conclude that **switch** is the winner here. Any improvement for the test or the code to get a better result?

Note : you can find the code [here](https://github.com/Gujarats/GetBadge/tree/master)

Comment: Switch is fast here because Go internally performs binary search if number of statements are more than 4 in switch case. Check: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/cmd/compile/internal/gc/swt.go

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @Phrancis thanks for your guidance. this is really help me to collaborate in this community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `GetReputationBadge`, you're needlessly allocating strings by modifying the `badge` variable. It would be a fairer benchmark to write it in the following way:

```
func GetReputationBadge(score int) string {
    if score >= 500001 {
        return "diamond-5.gif"
    }
    if score >= 200001 {
        return "diamond-4.gif"
    }
    // etc.
    if score >= 4501 {
        return "gold-1.gif"
    }
    return "badges-off.jpg"
}
```

(That said, I'm not convinced it matters — the compiler should probably optimize this anyway.)

I tried it and was very surprised to see that the benchmarks were still very poor. Turns out, you called the wrong function in your benchmark :-) `BenchmarkGetReputation1If` calls `benchmarkGetReputation` insead of `benchmarkGetReputationIf`. Retrying it with this fixed leads to the expected result:

```
BenchmarkGetReputation1-4           10000000       188 ns/op
BenchmarkGetReputation2-4           10000000       182 ns/op
BenchmarkGetReputation3-4           10000000       179 ns/op
BenchmarkGetReputation4-4           10000000       192 ns/op
BenchmarkGetReputation1Switch-4     300000000         4.55 ns/op
BenchmarkGetReputation2Switch-4     300000000         4.32 ns/op
BenchmarkGetReputation3Switch-4     300000000         4.63 ns/op
BenchmarkGetReputation4Switch-4     2000000000         0.84 ns/op
BenchmarkGetReputation1If-4         300000000         4.21 ns/op
BenchmarkGetReputation2If-4         300000000         4.19 ns/op
BenchmarkGetReputation3If-4         300000000         4.74 ns/op
BenchmarkGetReputation4If-4         2000000000         0.88 ns/op
```

Note that this benchmark is still pretty flawed: you're only testing it with a couple of values, so depending on which they are, the order of the if/else statements are going to matter. You should use much more values, picked among a reasonable distribution instead.

Comment: thank you for correcting the if-else statement. so it turns out the switch and if-else here is the same in terms of performance?

Comment: Yes; which I don't find surprising — they're pretty much the same thing with some syntaxic sugar. Ashwini's mentions that the switch is doing a binary search; but I don't expect this to change benchmarks significantly for switch statements with very simple conditions and less than a few dozen cases.

Comment: alright I will give this a try and let you know, I will add some more conditions to it and see the difference. For example above it only mention for gold badges. I will try with silver, bronze, etc

Comment: your benchmark and my benchmark is kinda different, I've got the same result as before when using if-else just like your suggestion. I will post the code in my github